# mongoose updating a field in a MongoDB not working

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have this code

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    Username: {type: String, index: true},
    Password: String,
    Email: String,
    Points: {type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

[...]

```
    var User = db.model('User');
   /*
    * Function to save the points in the user's account
    */
    function savePoints(name, points){
        if(name != "unregistered user"){
        User.find({Username: name}, function(err, users){

            var oldPoints = users[0].Points;
            var newPoints = oldPoints + points;

            User.update({name: name}, { $inc: {Points: newPoints}}, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log("some error happened when update");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("update successfull! with name = " + name);
                    User.find({Username: name}, function(err, users) { 
                        console.log("updated : " + users[0].Points);
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    }
}

savePoints("Masiar", 666);
```

I would like to update my user (by finding it with its name) by 
updating his/her points. I'm sure oldPoints and points contain a 
value, but still my user keep being at zero points. The console prints 
"update successful".

What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the stupid / noob question.

Masiar

Comment: can we see some more code? Something that can be reproduced as written would be most helpful.

Comment: sorry for that, here you are! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are doing a few unstandard things:

- Use `findOne` instead of `find` if you want to load just one user
- Calling `Model.update` should be done to update records that you have not loaded
- `$inc` is adding oldPoints, so the new value will be 2*oldPoints + newPoints
- You are using `name` as the conditional query instead of `Username`

I would rewrite the code into something like this:

```
User.findOne({Username: name}, function(err, user){
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  user.Points += points;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the issue was that I was not using findOne! The $inc was done because I didn't know if I was updating it right, thus I tried every possible command. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks it has solved a similar update issue for me. For which I was struggling for last 3 days.

Comment: It's bad practice. You can replace already existing and changed document between ```findOne...user.save``` calls.

Answer (score 0):

follow my code guy

```
 User.update({ username: "faibaa" },
    { $inc: { point: 200000 } }, function(err,data){
        return res.send(data);
    });
```

Comment: Not sure who you're speaking to ("guy?" Really?). But you posted to a question asked, and answered (with accepted answer), 5 years ago.