# Update a mongodb document using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From my nodejs app I am trying to run a very basic update statement which will modify the value of a specific field name userimage in users collection

```
var user = require('config/models/user');
user.update({_id:"547e34350727336c1bc8fd5a"}, {$set: {userimage:"abcd.jpg"}});
```

The statement is pretty much basic as you can see. Firstly I loaded the model file which defines the schema. And in the next time I am passing a hardcoded document id and trying to update the userimage field. The reord for the id exists in my collection. Also all field names are fine.

In the same file I have other fucntions such as insert is working properly.

Please help me understand where am I doing it wrong.

Just to clarify as bit more. My insert function works fine as below:

### Working Function

```
exports.register = function(name,designation,company,mobno,email,reg_id,callback) {

    var newuser = new user({
        name: name,
        designation: designation,
        company: company,
        mobno: mobno, 
        email: email,
        reg_id: reg_id,
        userimage: "",
        active:0});

        user.find({mobno: mobno},function(err,users){
        var len = users.length;

        if(len == 0){
            newuser.save(function (err) {   
            callback({'response':"200"});   
        });
        }else{
            callback({'response':"201"});
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You should check *error* callback of **update** query. If there will be an error, you can catch it in there.

Comment: Following has worked for me thanks for the tutorial

user.findOne({_id: userid}, function(err, user){
   if (err) { return next(err); }
   user.userimage = userimage;
   
   user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
   });
 });

Tutorial Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218770/mongoose-updating-a-field-in-a-mongodb-not-working?rq=1

Comment: The issue here is to catch an *error* in callback, not how to update specific document.